# Retorno null ao utilizar variável de tipo Double

Tags: java

Estou tendo dificuldades em alguns métodos(quando terá que retornar ou quando for void ,parâmetros ou não etc). Por quê os dois últimos métodos de Employee  está retornando null?

```
package employee;


public class Employee {
   private  String firstName,lastName;
   private  Double salarioMensal,anual,aumentoAnual;


public Employee(String nome,String sobrenome,double salario){

    firstName = nome;
    lastName = sobrenome;
    salarioMensal = salario;


}
public void setFirstName(String nome){

    firstName = nome;
}
 public void setlastName(String sobrenome){

     lastName = sobrenome;
 }
 public void setSalarioMensal(double salario){

     salarioMensal = salario;
 }
 public String getFirstName(){

     return firstName;
 }
 public String getLastName(){

     return lastName;
 }
 public Double getSalarioMensal(){

     return salarioMensal;

     }

 public void boasVindas(){

    System.out.printf("\n Seja bem vindo Sr(a) %s %s \n",getFirstName(),getLastName());
}
 public void setAnual(double salario){
    salarioMensal = salario;
     anual = salarioMensal*12;

 }
 public void setAmentoAnual(double anualtotal){
     anualtotal = anual;
     aumentoAnual = anualtotal*0.10;
 }
 public Double getAnual(){

     return anual;
 }
 public Double getAumentoAnual(){

     return aumentoAnual;
 }
 public void displayFinish1(){

     System.out.printf("\n Sr(a). %s .\nO seu salário acumulado em 12 meses será:%.2f.\n",getFirstName(),getAnual());
     System.out.printf("Após 12 meses terá um aumento de 10 por cento,ficando:\n %.2f \n.",getAumentoAnual());

 }

}
```

---

```
/***O TESTE****/

package employee;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class EmployeeTest {



    public static void main(String [] args){

    String nome,nome2 , sobrenome,sobrenome2;
    Double salario ,salario2;

Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.printf("\n Entre com o primeiro nome\n");
nome = entrada.nextLine();
System.out.printf("Entre com o Sobrenome\n");
sobrenome = entrada.nextLine();
System.out.printf("Entre com o salário mensal\n");
salario = entrada.nextDouble();

Employee employee1 = new Employee(nome,sobrenome,salario);

employee1.boasVindas();
employee1.displayFinish1();


    }

}
```

Comment: Seria porque você em momento algum definiu a variável `aumentoAnual`? Se não definir um valor, ela sempre sempre nula, por ser um tipo `Double`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Double` e `double` são coisas diferentes, daí talvez a sua surpresa. O primeiro é um objeto e, como tal, sempre que não for explicitamente inicializado, será `null` por padrão (é o mesmo comportamento da String, por exemplo). Se por acaso, entretanto, fosse `double`, ou seja, um tipo primitivo, a inicialização acontece automaticamente com o valor 0.0.

Desta forma, seus métodos retornam `null` simplesmente porque as variáveis manipuladas/exibidas por eles não foram explicitamente inicializadas com nenhum valor, ou seja, são `null`.

Para evitar este comportamento, você tem duas opções: 1) inicializá-las ou então mudar seu tipo para `double`.